# Is it possible to distinguish types with identical fully qualified names?

Tags: c#, vb.net, namespaces

The scenario is I would like to be able reference two similar 3rd party assemblies (e.g. assem1 and assem2) which both define a type with the same fully qualified name (e.g. Example.MyType).
Is there any way to distinguish between these and refernce them seperately? I believe the answer is no but confirmation or correction would be handy.

Edit: Answered for C# 2.0 and higher below but need an answer in VB.Net 1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly do it in C# - you need to use [extern aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) to specify which one you want in each case. Anson Horton has a [walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) which is useful.

I don't know whether VB has a similar feature.

Of course, it's worth avoiding this situation if you possibly can :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, this is exactly what i need. Unfortunately its only in C# 2.0 and higher and i need VB.Net 1.1 which i probably should have mentioned. I'll wait a while for other answers before giving you a tick.

Comment: @Rich: I'm afraid I don't even know if the feature is available in VB. If it is, I'd expect it to be in VB 8 (VS 2005) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question; if you want to reference it as part of a project (e.g. in VS), this isn't going to help you. But if you need to reference the type in a config file or whatever, the following does work:

Use the fully qualified name including the assemly name (best if the assembly is strong named), and you can tell them apart. Have a look at [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) for more information.